# Is it possible to plot a function using Plot3D and a curve using ParametricPlot3D in the same picture?

Tags: plotting

I'd like to plot a graph of a function using e.g. `Plot3D` and then a line (in general a curve, in my case a straight line, tangent at some point to the surface just drawn), using e.g. `ParametricPlot3D` *in the same picture*.  Is it possible?  If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `Show[]` for this. Eg:

```
Show[
 Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}],
 ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u], Sin[u] + Cos[v], Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 
   2 \[Pi]}, {v, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]
 ]
```